# issue while preparing jasper reports with large data

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using JRBeanDatasource in iReport and passing this datasource from my java code.
But I have large data . So getting OutOfMemory exception.
I have seen virtualizer concept but couldn't use as I am passing javabeandatasource and getting issue in storing all the data in datasource(memory).

Is there any way that I receive data and write directly in report instead of storing in memory.

I need to export as xlsx format, and all data should be in one sheet only.

Comment: specify what do you mean exactly `large data` .. what is the size expected of generated report ?

Comment: I have Datasource in my java code and I am passing it as parameter to my .jasper file , issue is while creating datasource I m getting out of memory, Datasource may contain 1 lac or more data.
I am using JRDataSource (POJo as my actual data).